# Install Ruby via RVM on CPanel System to use Unicorn via Apache mod_proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, centos, cpanel

I own a CentOS 6.0 System with CPanel 11.30.5 installed. I'm very new to CPanel.

I want to install Ruby using RVM in a user directory that will be created as a CPanel account (install it locally in a home directory, not on a system level). I want to run Unicorn (a Ruby application server) and have Apache act as a proxy. Unicorn will run on some port (eg. 3001) and I simply want to do what is usually done in an Apache Virtual Host as:

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3001
```

Anyway, I'm tempted to just open the virtual hosts file and add my directive but as per my understanding it's best not to mess with any of the system files on a CPanel box. So my question is: What is the proper CPanel way to add ProxyPass to a virtual host and is there anything I need to know that might be unexpected?

(I *do not* want Ruby installed system-wide or for use by others, just for this one account -- which I own and control -- so the CPanel specific implementation does not interest me.)

Thanks!

Comment: After some research I have found a page about adding custom directives on the CPanel site:

http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/EasyApache3/InsideVHost

That essentially answer the question.